# Where should I install varnish?

Tags: amazon-ec2, varnish

So my web app is hosted on amazon using Opswork.

Currently I have a 1 dedicated instance for Postgresql, 1 instance as my webserver, and another dedicated instance running Redis for caching purposes.

I would like to improve the performance by adding Varnish. Given my architecture where should I install varnish? and also taking into account I may soon outgrow this solucion and be using more webservers behind a loadbalancer.

Any help would be appreciated!

Bye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varnish will always be quicker if you run it with memory storage - so the one with the most free memory would be a good pick. Even if you don't have enough to spare for the storage, it also uses quite some memory for the connection handling when you reach a bit more traffic.

Further along the road when you want a load balancer a good start would be to use a dedicated server for varnish that also can do load balancing just fine. It's not as effecient as a lightweight dedicated loadbalancer but until you need multiple varnish servers (way down the road) there is generally no point in using anything before it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Varnish in front of Apache Web Server. However it's fine to reside on Web Server itself and point Load Balancers to Varnish.